# How do I alter a charset in MariaDB

Tags: mariadb, full-text-search

I want to include the # symbol as a valid word character in MariaDB full text search so I can use it to represent tags and make them searchable.

This is my sample data in the caption column which has a full text index. I included " and $ in my sample just in case I was off a character in the map.

```
A sample photo with three keywords #sunset "sunset $sunset.
```

I checked the charset for my table using `SELECT default_character_set_name FROM information_schema.SCHEMATA WHERE schema_name = “o810”` and it is 'latin1'.

I went to charsets/latin1.xml and updated the map to indicate # is a capital letter (assuming that makes it a valid word character).

```
<ctype>
<map>
 00
 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 28 28 28 28 28 20 20
 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20
 48 10 10 01 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10
 84 84 84 84 84 84 84 84 84 84 10 10 10 10 10 10
 10 81 81 81 81 81 81 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01
 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 10 10 10 10 10
 10 82 82 82 82 82 82 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02
 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 10 10 10 10 20
 10 00 10 02 10 10 10 10 10 10 01 10 01 00 01 00
 00 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 02 10 02 00 02 01
 48 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10
 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10
 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01
 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 10 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 02
 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02
 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 10 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02
</map>
</ctype>
```

I dropped the index, restarted mariadb and recreated the full text index.

If then used `SET GLOBAL innodb_ft_aux_table = 'o810/photo'` to dump the full text index. `SELECT * FROM INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE` shows "sunset" but does not include "#sunset", so # is not being included in the word.

I must be missing something obvious, but I cannot find it. Any help would be appreciated.

- I've tried different opening and saving charsets/Index.xml and charsets/latin1.xml.
- I've tried shifting my map change, just in case I could not count right.
- I've stopped and restarted the database server multiple times.
- I've deleted and recreated the full text index multiple times.
- I've searched high and low for more info.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Thanks @GeorgRichter, I'll get those images replaces to with formatted text.

Answer (score 0):

Changing character set definitions is a really bad idea, since this might have impact on other operations like sorting etc.

The preferred way is to modify the storage/innobase/include/fts0tokenize.h file in the server source and recompile the server.

For that you need just change the true_word_char() macro:

`#define true_word_char(c, ch) ((c) & (_MY_U | _MY_L | _MY_NMR) || (ch) == '_' || (ch) == '#')`